# SQLite error : if

Tags: sql, sqlite

This code gives the following error

```
create trigger age_check1
before insert on person 
for each row begin
if new.age < 0
then set new.age = 18;
end if;
end
```

ERROR :near "if": syntax error:

Comment: Because SQLite [has no IF](http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).

Comment: @CL. When I run this in MySql, then it gives error on "endif" . Any idea?

Comment: What has MySQL to do with this?

Comment: I mean, I tried to do the same thing in MySql as it has IF. But it does not work on MySql either

Comment: Why don't you just declare a default value for the column?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like SQLite doesnt support update `NEW` and then you should use after insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER age_check1
AFTER INSERT ON person 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.age < 0)
BEGIN
   UPDATE person 
   SET age = 18 
   WHERE id = NEW.id; // your primary key
END;
```